# E-Z system without a double bond

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, stereochemistry

Can we apply *E*-*Z* nomenclature to geometrical isomers without a double bond. For example, can we use it for *cis* and *trans* isomers of 1,2-dimethylcyclohexane?

Comment: No, those are (R,R)/(R,S)/(S,S).

Comment: @orthocresol: I didn't get your point. Shouldn't we use _E-Z_ system as an alternate to _cis-trans_ system of nomenclature when we go by the order of priority using CIP rule over _R-S_ system which is meant for the spatial orientation about a chirality centre?

Comment: @GuruVishnu, if you think about the point you're making, and think about whether the carbons in 1,2-dimethylcyclohexane are chiral... You're smart enough to figure it out. Furthermore, the *trans* diastereomer has two enantiomers, so you're restricting yourself to two letters to describe three different things. Let's be very clear here: the descriptors *cis* and *trans* have basically nothing to do with the IUPAC descriptors *Z* and *E*. They just so happen to be the same thing in the special case of a 1,2-disubstituted alkene.